# Variable not acessible when running vclick via js

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Array:

```
listaDisciplinas = [
{
    nome : "Nome",
    listaAtividades : []
}];
```

Code:

```
for(var i=0; i < listaDisciplinas.length; i++)
{
    var itemClick = $("<a />").html(listaDisciplinas[i].nome)
        .attr("href", "#listaAtividadesView")
        .attr("id", "disciplina_" + i);

    var element = $("<li />").html(itemClick);

    $("#listaDisciplinas").append(element);

    $(document).on("vclick", "#disciplina_" + i, function(e, data) 
    {
        updateListaAtividades(listaDisciplinas[i]);
    });
}
```

But, when I click on `addDisciplinaBtn`, it says: "Cannot read a property of undefined"

Why?

Comment: http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

An abstraction for tap and click events.

Comment: looks like `listaDisciplinas` is not defined

Comment: even if `listaDisciplinas` was defined, where's `i` defined ? Please share your full code .

Comment: But `listaDisciplinas` is avaiable. I checked it.

Comment: I'll add more details. But `i` is defined.

Comment: `.nome`. I used `.name` just to explain.

Comment: How does the array look like?

Comment: Most likely `i` isn't defined when `vclick` is triggered. For testing, replace it with 0 or 1. Edit: also, read more about binding events inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/event.data/

Data objects must be passed to `on`, via parameter:

```
.on("vclick", "#id", { /*Data here*/ }, function(event) { 
    /*Do what you want*/
    alert(event.data) 
});
```